# Compound verbs with infinitive and gerund

Tags: verbs, infinitives, gerunds

Which statements are grammatically correct and which meaning do they convey,

- This concept helps understand the problem.
- This concept helps to understand the problem.
- This concept helps understanding the problem.
- This concept helps in understanding the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'to help' is a verb that can be used transitively and intransitively.

An example of transitive use would be: A helped B do C.

An example of intransitive use would be: D helped.

Let's look at your examples in this light:

> This concept helps understand the problem.
>   This concept helps to understand the problem.

The sense of both of these is a transitive use of 'helps' (The concept helps [someone] (to) understand the problem), but the object ([someone]) is missing, so the verb appears to be intransitive, which goes against the sense.

> This concept helps understanding the problem. 
>   This concept helps in understanding the problem.

The sense of both of these is an intransitive use of 'helps'. Here 'understanding', as a gerund, means 'the act of understanding'. You need the preposition 'in' to convey the relationship grammatically.

Therefore,

> 'this concept helps in understanding the problem'

is the correct construction to use.